# Problem with internet connection in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, network-manager

I have a problem with my ubuntu. It’s version 18.04 and the problem is about internet connection. I have internet connection but after about 2 minutes it’s gonna lose. I don’t have any idea why it is happening.

Searched a lot and found this command:

```
sudo apt-get install remove network-manager*
```

And guess what? I dont have control center right now. Since i can’t plug LAN cable to connect internet i have to install it again. But how can i install it?

And please if you had something similar to my problem make me happy and help to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have another pc connected to internet, here you can download network manager packet: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/net/network-manager

Save to a pendrive, copy in your ubuntu machine and install the packet. Reboot after installation, and you have network manager installed. When you can connect your ubuntu machine to internet, run:

```
sudo apt-get update && upgrade
reboot
```

NOTE: on the same website you find dependecies for network manager packet. Download all the dependencies required to make it work.

**How to install packages**

Uncompress the archive, then install the package as follow:

```
tar -Jxf <compressed_archive>.tar.xz
sudo dpkg -i <uncompressed_package>.deb
```

Comment: Thank you TDK.but this command just extracts the package.

Comment: as you know dpkg is for installing deb packages. but the extracted folder is just a debian folder. without any ext.

Comment: i would expect a deb file... just choose your architecture in the table in the website, you should get a deb file compressed

Comment: Thanks. Yes deb file is the correct one. Solved.